# Local fonts to scss file in react

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, font-face

I am trying to import local font in scss file but when I run npm start I get the following errors

```
ERROR in ./src/components/Box/Box.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/AvenirNext-Bold-01.ttf' in 'C:\Users\evren\rcp\frontend\src\components\Box'
```

I have tried different solutions  but could not fix this problem.

This is how I import local font file in scss

[image]

Appreciate if someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check the URL in your request. what have you tried so far? try `'./fonts/AvernirNext-Bold-01.ttf'` seems to me you are looking inside the component not the root folder. As you can see in the error log the path is `'C:\Users\evren\rcp\frontend\src\components\Box'`

A way I implemented this is by adding:
*in scss folder > theme.scss*

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Light";
    src: url("fonts/Proxima Nova Light.eot");
    src: local("☺"),
    url("fonts/Proxima Nova Light.woff") format("woff"),
    url("fonts/Proxima Nova Light.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("fonts/Proxima Nova Light.svg") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

*in your app.js:*

```
@import "scss/theme.scss";

body {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Light", sans-serif;
}
```

*and finally fonts folder > src/fonts*

```
eot / ttf / woff / svg files go here
```

Comment: I have tried in that way and './src/fonts/AvernirNext-Bold-01.ttf ' too but I'm getting the same error

Comment: It would be helpful to add a screenshot of your tree.I will also update my answer.